# VSTO 2010 for MS Project

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I am using VSTO 2010 for MS Project.Iam loading tasks from sql server.Which will be loading data row by row.It slows the performance as it is loading task one by one.has Everyone any idea about how to load data in one go.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

don't load row by row. Load it table by table... Let your SQL-server do all the hard work-its designed to.

Comment: Please post your code and i can try to see where your code is slow and help out where i can.

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like below:

```
MSProject.Tasks mspTask = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject.Tasks;
 for (int i = 0; i < dsTaskList.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
DataRow drTask = dsTaskList.Tables[0].Rows[i];
                        short outLevel = Convert.ToInt16(drTask["TASK_OUTLINE_LEVEL"]);
                        if (outLevel == 0)
                        {

                            continue;

                        }

                        mspTask.Add();

                        Utility.Save_UID.Add(drTask["TASK_UID"].ToString());


                        Utility.editText9Bycode = true;
                        mspTask[k].Text9 = drTask["TASK_UID"].ToString();

                        string strAss = ""; 
                        DataSet dsAss =       WebServiceCall.GetAssignments(drTask["TASK_UID"].ToString());
```

}